# Using && operators in jquery while checking if checkbox is "checked"

Tags: jquery, checkbox

So basically what I'm trying to do is to make a series of elements appear when a checkbox is checked and if it has a particular class. But only if the checkbox is checked.

Here is the code for an individual checkbox and class:

```
$('#arcuate').change(function() {
  if ($('#arcuate').checked == true && $('.card').hasClass('arcuate') ) {
    $('.card').addClass('reveal')
  } else {
    $('.card').removeClass('reveal')
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery objects](http://api.jquery.com/) don't have a `checked` property; DOM checkbox elements do. So either

```
if ($("#arcuate").prop("checked") && ...
```

or

```
if ($("#arcuate")[0].checked && ...
```

or

```
if (document.getElementById("arcuate").checked && ...
```

I would use the first, which will return `undefined` if there is no `#arcuate` element (whereas the other two will throw errors).

---

Side notes:

1. `$('.card').hasClass(...)` will only check if the **first** element matching `.card` has the classs, but `$('.card').addClass(...)` and `$('.card').removeClass(...)` will add/remove the class from all matching elements. (Maybe that's what you wanted, but I thought I'd flag it up.)
2. `== true` is never necessary in a condition.
3. `toggleClass` could make that code more concise:

```js
$('#arcuate').change(function() {
    var cards = $('.card');
    cards.toggleClass("reveal", $('#arcuate').prop("checked") && cards.hasClass('arcuate'));
});
```

Or if you wanted to toggle each card individually:

```
$('#arcuate').change(function() {
    var checked = $('#arcuate').prop("checked");
    $('.card').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.toggleClass("reveal", checked && $this.hasClass('arcuate'));
    });
});
```

Comment: That did it, thanks. Was a combination of that and an html mix up. Appreciate the help.